# Which is the good way to link two resources in rest apis

Tags: api-design

Now, I'm starting to develop my web apis using expressjs.
I'm considering which is the good way to link two resources (two resource already exist in the database).

For example, I have two entities: `company` and `user`.
The relationship between `company` & `user` is one to many.

So, the user entity should contains the company_id.
There are some ways to link a user to a company.

Case 1:

```
PUT /users/{user_id}

Request: 
{
  "company_id": "abc"
}
```

Case 2:

```
PUT /company/{company_id}/users/{user_id}
```

I prefer with case 1 because in the future when relationships grow such as `deparment` & `user`, I don't need to expand my url to support these cases. But I don't know whether it is following the best practices of designing a restful apis or not.

Comment: I would advise against either case actually. A PUT request is meant to modify the entire resource. You are merely modifying a single field (company_id) in that request. A PATCH request with the body you provided in case 1 would make more sense.
An even better approach would be create a new entity all together that is "attached" to your entities. 
Something like
POST /users/{user_id}/companyAssociation
Or something similar

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend the latter option under no circumstances.
You can check HTTP RFC and some good articles like:

- [Restful API guidelines](https://github.com/byrondover/api-guidelines/blob/master/Guidelines.md#put)

  [Restful API design](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#patch-vs-put)

The general idea is that the resource is uniquely identified by its URL(the are exceptions to it, like with versioning but let's not focus on it for now) and when you apply a PUT to a resource using its URL `/company/{company_id}/users/{user_id}`, you should be performing an operation on this specific resource. It is not intuitive and transparent when by addressing one resource you are changing another one.

Comment: Going across this answer. The aformentioned link is broken (Restful API guidelines), instead use the following: https://github.com/byrondover/api-guidelines/blob/master/Guidelines.md

Comment: Based on your reply, the Restful API guidelines state the former solution => Golden Rules: Golden Rules => 1.Flat is better than nested.

Answer (score 3):

Either is acceptable. I prefer the former because of the flexibility it grants. In case 2, if you want to find all the users with the last name of 'Smith' regardless of what company they belong to, you're out of luck.